# Getting undefined when trying to get parent field attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Initially, I had one button to upload a photo

She looked like this, and the script for uploading specifically for this id

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Photos</label>
    <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="5">
        <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_form">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
        </a>
        <div id="dz_params_field_photo" 
            data-type="pipeline" data-entity_id="11" 
            style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div id="dz_field_photo_uploaded"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But then I needed to make several of these download buttons, and each button should have its own download

I've added these buttons so that I don't have to make a separate script for each button, I'm trying to tag them with different IDs so that one script can be used

But I have a problem in the script itself, specifically in getting the values ​​of `data attr` from `html`

This is not a complete script, I shortened it as much as possible for demonstration, otherwise I usually used the script to download from the dropzone, and the ID was indicated there at the beginning of initialization, but now I need to separately receive the ID for each button

And here I have a problem, I try to get `data-field_photo_id` from the `field_info` field but I get `undefined`, and for some reason it turns out for any attribute of any field

```js
(function($){
    $.dispatcherFiles = {
        $filesDropzone: null,
        $parallelUploads: 100,
        $maxFiles: 10,
        $files: [],

        cacheDom: function(){
            this.$body = $('body');
        },

        functions: {
            uploadFiles: function (e) {
                let field = $(e.currentTarget).closest('field').find('field_info');
                let photoID = $(e.currentTarget).closest('field').find('field_info').attr('data-field_photo_id');
                console.log(field);
                console.log(photoID);
            },
        },

        events: function(){
            this.$body.on('click', '.field .field_form .btnUpload', this.functions.uploadFiles.bind(this));
        },

        init: function () {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.events();
        }
    };

    $.dispatcherFiles.init();

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.field {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>

<div class="field">
    <label>Photos</label>
    <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="5">
        <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_form">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
        </a>
        <div id="dz_params_field_photo_5" 
            data-type="pipeline" data-entity_id="11" 
            style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div id="dz_field_photo_5_uploaded"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label>Photos</label>
    <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="6">
        <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_form">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
        </a>
        <div id="dz_params_field_photo_6" 
            data-type="pipeline" data-entity_id="12" 
            style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div id="dz_field_photo_6_uploaded"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label>Photos</label>
    <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="7">
        <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_form">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
        </a>
        <div id="dz_params_field_photo_7" 
            data-type="pipeline" data-entity_id="13" 
            style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div id="dz_field_photo_7_uploaded"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: probably you have to rename it to different classes such that ```field1```, ```field2```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code missing the *class* symbol (`.`) in the following lines:

```
let field = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.field').find('.field_info');
let photoID = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.field').find('.field_info').attr('data-field_photo_id');
```